# async function doesn't work in the gulpfile.babel.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp, babeljs

I have a 1gulpfile.babel.js with such code inside (where async-function should be assigned as an error handler for the gulp task):

```
// Load Node Modules/Plugins
import gulp from 'gulp';
import concat from 'gulp-concat';
// import myth from 'gulp-myth';
import uglify from 'gulp-uglify'; 
import jshint from 'gulp-jshint'; 
import imagemin from 'gulp-imagemin';
import connect from 'connect';
import serve from 'serve-static';
import browsersync from 'browser-sync';
import postcss from 'gulp-postcss';
import cssnext from 'postcss-cssnext';
import cssnano from 'cssnano';
import browserify from 'browserify';
import source from 'vinyl-source-stream';
import buffer from 'vinyl-buffer';
import babelify from 'babelify';
import plumber from 'gulp-plumber';
import del from 'del';
import config from './config.json';
import sourcemaps from 'gulp-sourcemaps';

import regeneratorRuntime from "regenerator-runtime";


// Error Handler
async function onError(err) {
    console.log('Name:', err.name);
    console.log('Reason:', err.reason);
    console.log('File:', err.file);
    console.log('Line:', err.line);
    console.log('Column:', err.column);
}

var cssFiles = ['app/css/main.css', 'app/css/*.css'];
// Styles Task
gulp.task('styles', () => {
    return gulp.src(cssFiles)
        .pipe(plumber(
            {
            errorHandler: onError
            }
        ))
        .pipe(concat('all.css'))
        .pipe(postcss([
            cssnext(),
            cssnano()
        ]))
        .pipe(plumber.stop())
        .pipe(gulp.dest(config.css.dest));
});
```

also in this (root project) directory is package.json file:

```
{
  "name": "gulp-book",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "A simple gulp project...",
  "main": "gulpfile.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "ms",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.26.3",
    "babel-loader": "^8.2.5",
    "babel-polyfill": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.7.0",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-stage-0": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-register": "^6.26.0",
    "babelify": "^8.0.0",
    "beeper": "^3.0.0",
    "browser-sync": "^2.27.9",
    "browserify": "^17.0.0",
    "connect": "^3.7.0",
    "cssnano": "^5.1.7",
    "del": "^6.0.0",
    "gulp": "^4.0.2",
    "gulp-concat": "^2.6.1",
    "gulp-imagemin": "^7.1.0",
    "gulp-jshint": "^2.1.0",
    "gulp-plumber": "^1.2.1",
    "gulp-postcss": "^9.0.1",
    "gulp-sass": "^5.1.0",
    "gulp-sourcemaps": "^3.0.0",
    "gulp-uglify": "^3.0.2",
    "jshint": "^2.13.4",
    "postcss-cssnext": "^3.1.1",
    "regenerator-runtime": "^0.13.9",
    "serve-static": "^1.15.0",
    "vinyl-buffer": "^1.0.1",
    "vinyl-source-stream": "^2.0.0"
  }
}
```

and .babelrc file:

```
{
    "presets": [ "es2015", "stage-0" ]
}
```

When I'm executing `gulp --gulpfile 1gulpfile.babel.js styles` command I'm getting and error:

```
[18:55:28] Requiring external module babel-register                                                                                   
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'default')                                                                        
at C:\Users\Sergey\Documents\code\web\Getting-Started-with-Gulp-Second-Edition\gulpfile.babel.js:5:69                                 
at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Sergey\Documents\code\web\Getting-Started-with-Gulp-Second-Edition\gulpfile.babel.js:28:2)            
at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1103:14)                                                                         
at loader (C:\Users\Sergey\Documents\code\web\Getting-Started-with-Gulp-Second-Edition\node_modules\babel-register\lib\node.js:144:5)                                                                                                                                       
at Object.require.extensions.<computed> [as .js] (C:\Users\Sergey\Documents\code\web\Getting-Started-with-Gulp-Second-Edition\node_modules\babel-register\lib\node.js:154:7)                                                                                                
at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)                                                                              
at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)                                                                    
at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19)                                                                          
at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)                                                                                 
at requireOrImport (C:\Users\Sergey\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\gulp-cli\lib\shared\require-or-import.js:19:11)
```

So the question is - what is the error and how I can handle with it?

Comment: Your `onError` function does not need to be async. Just change `async function onError` to `function onError`.

Comment: Thanks, but actually I'm (I should to use) an async function in onError handler here (it is just missing in this code example)